# print leaf nodes of binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

I am wrriting a recursive function that prints out leaf nodes of a binary tree. 
Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void printLeafNodes(BinaryNode<AnyType> t)
{
      if(t == NULL)       
        return;
       if(t.left == NULL && t.right==NULL)      
          System.out.println(t.element); 
       else if(t.left != NULL && t.right == NULL) 
       printLeafNodes(t.left); 

       else 
             printLeafNodes(t.right);      
}
```

I would very much appreciate if someone can pinpoint any flows in my logic.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: @defaultlocale, I just wanted to know if there is any logical error in my method. Also, if there is a better way to write it.

Comment: I'm glad that someone have managed to answer your question. But you should note that `you should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face` (check out the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)). In its current form your question is not practically answerable and leads to extended discussion. Also it doesn't show research effort: you just want someone else to test and debug this code for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public static void printLeafNodes(BinaryNode<AnyType> t)
{
      if(t == NULL)       
        return;
       if(t.left == NULL && t.right==NULL)      
          System.out.println(t.element); 
       printLeafNodes(t.left); 
       printLeafNodes(t.right);      
}
```

Comment: Is it better to return after printing and save two calls, since it is known that `t.left` and `t.right` are null?

Comment: @Alexandre, that makes sense I guess.

Comment: @jonhopkins, what do you mean by that? An example will help

Comment: `if (t.left == NULL && t.right == NULL) { System.out.println(t.element); return; }` Since `t.left` and `t.right` are null, there's not much sense in continuing the function to call `printLeafNodes` on those nodes, since those calls will just immediately return, so instead just stop the function right after printing. It's not a necessary step, but it saves the program from having to call `printLeafNodes` twice when it doesn't really have to.

Comment: @jonhopkins, i See your point now. Good catch!